# C# WPF creating form from json, when json can change from one element to another

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I'm creating C# WPF .xaml form. The element I display has: Name, Metadata, Number of records. The problem is, is that metadata is .json string that can consist of pretty much anything and I need it to be displayed and changed (later if needed). One time it can be: 
`{"name":"jeff","lastname":"Jefferson","notes":"cool guy"}`

and on the other object it can be something like:

`{"Id":"jeff","surname":"Jefferson","description":"cool guy","firstTimeSeen":"2020-03-25"}`

What would be the suggested way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop throught the key-value pairs that represent yet another JSON object and manually create, let say, `TextBlock` for each one. That's the simplest approach I can imagine.

Comment: So: deserialize .json into something like -> List<Key, Value> then create ListBox with TextBlock for Key and TextBlock for Value in it and then just loop the pairs till the List ends. Yeah, it seems like the simplest approach indeed. Ty man.

Comment: @SimasPaškauskas, don't forget to add your list as a child to a parent `Panel`. You have to reference it by name from the code-behind `xaml.cs` file.